# Jar file packaged in install4J is getting exposed after installation of exe

Tags: install4j

I'm testing out Install4J 5.1.5 and am running into a little issue. My original jar file (my coding files) are available in directory after installation of my exe (created using install4j).  So how to secure my files from being explore? any idea?

Comment: Do you mean your *.java source files are included in the installation?

Answer (score 0):

install4j does not try to hide your JAR files. It is also not an effective way of securing your IP. The only thing that really works is an obfuscator. See [proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) for a free example.